# Не работает INSERT INTO Python

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

Я пытаюсь вставить вот эти значения в таблицу, но всё время ошибка в VALUE. Все типы уже раз 10 перепроверил, всё возвращается правильно.
Использую PostgreSQL

```
data = {"t": "fasd", "m": "inbox@sfsdf.dsa", "d": "dsdsdsds", "p": "444",}
cursor.execute(f"""INSERT INTO bugs VALUE ({new_id}, 0, '{data["t"]}', '{data["d"]}', '{data["m"]}', '{data["p"]}')""")
```

Comment: Может надо VALUES?

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, ЮрийСПб! Да, нужно просто поменять на VALUES

```
data = {"t": "fasd", "m": "inbox@sfsdf.dsa", "d": "dsdsdsds", "p": "444",}
cursor.execute(f"""INSERT INTO bugs VALUES ({new_id}, 0, '{data["t"]}', '{data["d"]}', '{data["m"]}', '{data["p"]}')""")
```